# DJANGO Serializer Validation Never Called

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to run custom validation on a serializer in Django. The serializer is as simple as:

```
class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(many=False, required=False, allow_null=True)

    def validate(self, data):

        print('Validating')
        print(data)
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["id", "user", "type", "title", "content", "created_ts"]
        read_only_fields = ["id", "user", "created_ts"]
```

And the serializer is called as such:

```
def create_post(self, request):
      serializer = PostsSerializer(data=request.data)

      if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
         #echo something
      else:
           fail
```

And the model is this:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.db import models
from ..enums import PostTypes


class Post(models.Model):


    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=[(tag.name, tag.value) for tag in PostTypes])
    title = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "post"
        ordering = ["-created_ts"]
        verbose_name = "Post"
        verbose_name_plural = "posts"
```

Any idea what would be causing the validate function not to execute?

Comment: Where is the create_post method located? in the view? are you sure the method is ever called? can you put print statements in it and check? Also post the full code of your view

Comment: @Ken4scholars The create_post is ina viewset and I do print(request.data) on which returns the data, so I am positive it is being called. Nothing  is printed via the print variable in validation.

Comment: Please post the viewset code. How do you call that method? because it's not a standard viewset method. Also not that validate is only called the DRF standard validation passes. In this case only when is_valid is true

Comment: Have you tried to verify if you can validate a single field via the serializer?  Such as `def validate_user(self, value):  print(value)`?  Or, have you verified that `request.data` is a dictionary?

Comment: Try adding `"print (serializer.errors)"` after `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`. What will be printed?  Perhaps the error was earlier than `Validate` was called.